# How mvn find classes defined in another project's test directory

Tags: maven, compilation

For short, two projects: tddl-matrix and tddl-rule. The tests in the tddl-maxtrix reports that classes that are defined in tddl-rule's test package not found.

Detail:
There are many tests in both projects, and tests in tddl-matmrix depends on some classes (e.g., TestUtils) that are defined in tddl-rule.

For example:
A test in tddl-rule is:

```
package com.taobao.tddl.rule;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
public class TestUtils {

    public static final int GreaterThan        = Comparative.GreaterThan;
    public static final int GreaterThanOrEqual = Comparative.GreaterThanOrEqual;
    public static final int Equivalent         = Comparative.Equivalent;
    public static final int NotEquivalent      = Comparative.NotEquivalent;
    public static final int LessThan           = Comparative.LessThan;
}
```

Then another test in tddl-matrix is:

```
import static com.taobao.tddl.rule.TestUtils.Equivalent;
import static com.taobao.tddl.rule.TestUtils.GreaterThan;

import com.taobao.tddl.rule.TestUtils;
public class BigDecimalPartDiscontinousRangeEnumeratorUnitTest{
...
}
```

The test in tddl-matrix depends on the class `TestUtils`, which is in the tddl-rule's test's directory.

When I ran `mvn install -DskipTests`, it is ok in one machine, but fail in another one (the error indicates that `TestUtils` cannot be found.). So I am very puzzled:

1. Why the compilation is OK in one machine. I went to the local repository: `c:\..\.m2\replository\com\..\tddl-rule\`, and I could not find any class naming `TestUtils`. This class only exists in tddl-rule's project's target directory.

The pom of tddl-matrix is something like:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.taobao.tddl</groupId>
        <artifactId>tddl</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.7-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.taobao.tddl</groupId>
    <artifactId>tddl-matrix</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>${project.artifactId} module for tddl ${project.version}</name>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>tddl-optimizer</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        .....
        <!-- Test libs -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

And the `mvn dependency:tree` is:

```
[INFO] com.taobao.tddl:tddl-matrix:jar:5.1.7-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- com.taobao.tddl:tddl-common:jar:5.1.7-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  ...
[INFO] +- com.taobao.tddl:tddl-optimizer:jar:5.1.7-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.taobao.tddl:tddl-rule:jar:5.1.7-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:2.5.6.SEC03:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:2.5.6.SEC03:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:2.5.6.SEC03:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:jar:2.1.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.taobao.tddl:tddl-parser:jar:5.1.7-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  \- cglib:cglib-nodep:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] \- junit:junit:jar:4.11:test
[INFO]    \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
```

Comment: If you have test classes of one project depending on another project that sounds you don't really have unit tests or some other sort of code smell in your tests...technically you can create a [test-jar from the test classes](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/create-test-jar.html) of the needed project but I don't recommend it. The best is to create a separate project which contains the common classes and make it a dependency (as JF Meier already wrote).

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you cannot use test classes of other Maven projects. IMHO you should not do it even if you could. If you need utility classes to test different artifacts, write a test-utilities.jar and use it as `test` dependency in all test cases.